# Reset stored values at pagebreaks and environment boundaries

Tags: macros, conditionals

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449381/how-to-properly-use-declareoption-within-a-macro/449388#449388) question, I have created a simple macro that prints and stores its argument, and if it is issued again with the identical argument it prints nothing:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\newenvironment{myenv}{\ignorespaces}{\par\ignorespacesafterend}

\DeclareOption{skiprepetitions}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\mypackage@print\mypackage@print@skip}%
}
\DeclareOption{keeprepetitions}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\mypackage@print\mypackage@print@keep}%
}
\ExecuteOptions{keeprepetitions}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\def\mypackage@storedval{} % create a macro to later store a value in

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {% if empty just print an empty line
     \mbox{}%
    }
    {% if not empty
     \mypackage@print{#1}%
     \def\mypackage@storedval{#1}%
    }%
}

\def\mypackage@print@skip#1{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\mypackage@storedval}}
   {\mbox{}}
   {#1}%
}
\def\mypackage@print@keep#1{#1\\}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[skiprepetitions]{mypackage}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
\mycommand{A} \\ %A
\mycommand{A} \\  %empty
\mycommand{A} \\  %empty
\mycommand{} \\    %empty
\mycommand{B} \\  %B
\mycommand{C} \\  %C
\mycommand{C} \\  %empty
\mycommand{A} \\  %A
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
\mycommand{A} \\ %A  
\mycommand{A} \\ %empty

\newpage

\mycommand{A} \\ %A 
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I would like to now have it "reset" or "forget" what is stored at pagebreaks and boundaries of a specific environment, so that on a new page, or in a new environment it *does* print its argument even if the previous one was identical.

Outcommented in the document above are the values that I expect to see.

Comment: in general (unless all your page breaks are forced) you would need a two pass system leaving markers and checking page numbers, eg via  \pageref. Fortunately there is a package for do most of the work for you, see the `perpage` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Hmm, I don't quite understand how though.  So `perpage` seems to reset counters, but how do I get it to reset the value that I'm storing in that macro?  In general even at environment boundaries I don't know how to reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, the following does what you want (thanks to [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483648/reset-stored-values-at-pagebreaks-and-environment-boundaries#comment1222767_483648) for the hint about `perpage`!):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\RequirePackage{perpage}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\MakePerPage{mycounter}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  % \mycommand is only defined inside the environment
  \let\mycommand\my@command
  % Make sure the next \mycommand isn't ignored, even if its argument
  % matches the value stored in \mypackage@storedval.
  \setcounter{mycounter}{0}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \par\ignorespacesafterend
}

\DeclareOption{skiprepetitions}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\mypackage@print\mypackage@print@skip}%
}
\DeclareOption{keeprepetitions}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\mypackage@print\mypackage@print@keep}%
}
\ExecuteOptions{keeprepetitions}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\def\mypackage@storedval{} % create a macro to later store a value in

\newcommand{\my@command}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {% if empty just print an empty line
     \mbox{}%
    }%
    {% If this is the first \stepcounter{mycounter} executed since the current
     % page was started, this sets 'mycounter' to 1.
     \stepcounter{mycounter}%
     \mypackage@print{#1}%
     \def\mypackage@storedval{#1}%
    }%
}

\def\mypackage@print@skip#1{%
  \ifthenelse{\cnttest{\value{mycounter}}>{1}\AND
              \equal{#1}{\mypackage@storedval}}%
   {\mbox{}}%
   {#1}%
}
\def\mypackage@print@keep#1{#1\\}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skiprepetitions]{mypackage}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{myenv}
\mycommand{A}\\  %A
\mycommand{A}\\  %empty
\mycommand{A}\\  %empty
\mycommand{}\\   %empty
\mycommand{B}\\  %B
\mycommand{C}\\  %C
\mycommand{C}\\  %empty
\mycommand{A}\\  %A
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
\mycommand{A}\\ %A
\mycommand{A}\\ %empty

\newpage

\mycommand{A}\\ %A
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I used a new counter called `mycounter` that is subject to `\MakePerPage{mycounter}`. This implies that the first `\stepcounter{mycounter}` on any given page resets `mycounter` to 1,<sup>a</sup> because 1 is the default value of the optional argument of `\MakePerPage`.

I made it so that at the beginning of `myenv`, `mycounter` is set to 0. Besides, `\stepcounter{mycounter}` is executed whenever `\mycommand` is called with a non-empty argument. Therefore, after this `\stepcounter{mycounter}` is performed, `mycounter` is equal to 1 if and only if:

- this is the first `\mycommand` call on the current page, or;
- this is the first `\mycommand` call in the current `myenv` environment.

This is the basis for the “ignoring criterion” you need. The only other thing to check is that, when we are in “possibly-ignoring mode”,<sup>b</sup> the argument passed to `\mycommand` differs from the saved value (since all this comes *after* the emptyness check).

Note that I renamed your `\mycommand` to `\my@command` and do `\let\mycommand\my@command` only inside the `myenv` environment, so that if you have a call to `\mycommand` that lies out of any `myenv` environment, LaTeX will report an error (undefined command).

You may want to move the `\stepcounter{mycounter}` call at the beginning of the `\my@command` macro: this depends on the behavior you want when an empty argument is passed. Should it make the new state be “possibly-ignoring mode”, or should it let the state unchanged (in my code: the latter)? This is a decision that belongs to you. But since you just output an `\mbox{}` for empty arguments, the difference won't be very visible in general...

[image]

**Footnotes**

---

a. After two compilation runs, since the `perpage` package relies on the `.aux` file.

b. I.e., the argument is non-empty and the `\mycommand` call is neither the first-on-page nor the first-in-environment.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I added a little discussion on the handling of empty arguments, because there is a policy decision to make that I believe wasn't precisely specified in the question (or else, I missed it).

Comment: Quick further question:  What exactly does `\def\mypackage@print@keep#1{#1\\}` do?  (right before `\end{filecontents}`) I'm trying to understand the code and that part is still obscure to me  (outcommenting doesnt' seem to have an effect) ...

Comment: It just prints its argument followed by ``\\`` (some sort of carriage return). I suppose you knew that. Now, in the big picture of your `.sty`, it ensures that when `keeprepetitions` is used as a package option (and isn't followed by `skiprepetitions`), `\mypackage@print` is a very dumb macro that just prints its argument and then starts a new line. In other words, the option `keeprepetitions` uses this macro (indirectly: `\mycommand` → `\my@command` → `\mypackage@print` → `\mypackage@print@keep`) to disable all the smart logic, except the check for emptyness of the argument.

Comment: ... the intricacies of markup :)

Comment: Yep, now I have bookmarked [how-do-i-mark-inline-code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code). It took me some time to find again, but saved my life. :) Did you understand my explanation? Do you understand `\let`? Because it's the main actor regarding your question.

Comment: I do.  I had forgotten that I had that option `keeprepetitions` :P   Concerning `\let`, yes, I wasn't aware of that trick but it's neat.    I might want to keep the option to use the command outside of the environment though (without any of the extra stuff), so I'll probably not use it though.  It shouldn't break anything else, should it?

Comment: You can skip the indirection through `\my@command` in this case, I don't think it will cause any problem. Except maybe that the counter is reset to 0 only when the environment is entered, so repetitions may be skipped if you use `\mycommand` out of the environment. But maybe this is what you expect, after all.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again:  I'm trying to incorporate the code now into a larger framework and for some weird reason, when issuing the command nested in some other environments, it ceases to work.  Any ideas why.  Here is my project  https://www.overleaf.com/1791495566wqkfvrtrnymd  which is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299264/interlinear-glosses-with-overlaps-line-numbers-and-speaker-labels) framework for linguists ...

Comment: Hmmm, I have no account at Overleaf and will be off for tonight, sorry. Try to make a MWE, as usual...

Comment: Oh, I see, ok, I'm sure the community will have some ideas ;)

Comment: Just FYI, the issue I had was that I needed to use `gdef` to update the stored value globally.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484217/problem-with-stored-values-macro-options-and-interaction-with-other-package/484255#484255)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up and glad to see you could sort it out!