# Problem with stored values, macro options, and interaction with other package

Tags: macros, conditionals, expex, options

Apologies for the rather general title, while trying to sort out a very specific problem:
I'm trying to enhance the framework that Alan Munn provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299264/interlinear-glosses-with-overlaps-line-numbers-and-speaker-labels) 
to represent naturally occurring discourse (with some extras, omitted here), with code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483648/reset-stored-values-at-pagebreaks-and-environment-boundaries/483706#483706) answer by frougon. 
The point of it all is to have a mechanism for Alan's code (which uses the `expex` package) to not print repeated labels of speakers.  I thought I would be able to integrate the two solutions, yet, with increased complexity, somehow along the way I managed to screw it up and for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong.

This is as minimal a WE as it gets:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{discourse.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{discourse}

\RequirePackage[user,savepos]{zref}
\RequirePackage{expex}
\newcounter{linenum}
\newlength{\largestspkr}
\newlength{\largestnum}
\newcommand{\deflargestlabel}[2][99]{
\settowidth{\largestnum}{#1}
\settowidth{\largestspkr}{~#2}}
\deflargestlabel[999]{speaker~99}

\RequirePackage{perpage}

\newcounter{spkrcounter}
    \MakePerPage{spkrcounter}

\newenvironment{discourseenv}{%
  \setcounter{linenum}{0}%
  \setcounter{spkrcounter}{0}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \par\ignorespacesafterend
}

\DeclareOption{skiprepetitions}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\discourse@print\discourse@print@skip}%
}
\DeclareOption{keeprepetitions}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\discourse@print\discourse@print@keep}%
}
\ExecuteOptions{skiprepetitions}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\def\discourse@storedval{} % create a macro to later store a value in

\newcommand{\spkr}[1]{%
  % create line numbers:
  \refstepcounter{linenum}\makebox[\largestnum][r]{\thelinenum}\hspace{1em}
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\makebox[\largestspkr][l]{}}% if empty > empty box
    {% If this is the first \stepcounter{spkrcounter} executed since the current
     % page was started, this sets 'spkrcounter' to 1.
     \stepcounter{spkrcounter}% 
     \discourse@print{#1}%
     \def\discourse@storedval{#1}%
    }%
}

\def\discourse@print@skip#1{%
  \ifthenelse{\cnttest{\value{spkrcounter}}>{1}\AND
        \equal{#1}{\discourse@storedval}}%
   {\makebox[\largestspkr][l]{}}% if repeated > empty box
   {\makebox[\largestspkr][l]{#1:}}%
}
\def\discourse@print@keep#1{\makebox[\largestspkr][l]{#1:}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{discourse}

\begin{document}

Here it works:

\spkr{A} OK

\spkr{A} OK

\spkr{B} OK

\spkr{A} OK

\vbox{}
Here too in the environment:

\begin{discourseenv}

\spkr{A} OK

\spkr{A} OK

\spkr{B} OK

\end{discourseenv}

\vbox{}
But in combination with expex it screws up:

\begin{discourseenv}

\ex[exno=\spkr{A}, exnoformat=X] OK (prints A) \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{A}, exnoformat=X] OK (empty) \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{B}, exnoformat=X] OK (prints B) \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{A}, exnoformat=X] OK (empty) \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{B}, exnoformat=X] OK (prints B) \xe

\end{discourseenv}

\begin{discourseenv}

\ex[exno=\spkr{B}, exnoformat=X] OK (prints B) \xe

\newpage

\ex[exno=\spkr{B}, exnoformat=X] OK (prints B) \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{B}, exnoformat=X] This one should be empty \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{B}, exnoformat=X] This one should be empty \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{A}, exnoformat=X] This one should print A  \xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{A}, exnoformat=X] OK (empty) \xe

\end{discourseenv}

\end{document}
```

It works as expected on the first couple of instances of the `\spkr` macro, but on the next page it behaves weirdly.  Anyone able to spot what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the definition global, because `\ex ... \xe` is performed inside a group.

```
\newcommand{\spkr}[1]{%
  % create line numbers:
  \refstepcounter{linenum}\makebox[\largestnum][r]{\thelinenum}\hspace{1em}
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\makebox[\largestspkr][l]{}}% if empty > empty box
    {% If this is the first \stepcounter{spkrcounter} executed since the current
     % page was started, this sets 'spkrcounter' to 1.
     \stepcounter{spkrcounter}%
     \discourse@print{#1}%
     \gdef\discourse@storedval{#1}% <--- global!!!
    }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you!!   Quick question: That only applies to where I update the stored value?  To define it first  `\gdef\discourse@storedval{}`  would be unnecessary?

Comment: @jan You could do it for uniformity, but since the macro gets first defined at the top level, there's no problem in using `\def`.